# Why isn't SQL Server using my index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

In our database we have this table with 200.000 rows

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.UserTask (
    UserTask_ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    UserTask_SequenceNumber int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    UserTask_IdEntitat uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    UserTask_Subject varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    UserTask_Description varchar(500) NOT NULL,
            .....
            .....
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserTask] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [UserTask_ID] ASC
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have created an index on `UserTask_IdEntitat` column with

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_UserTask_IDEntitat ON dbo.UserTask 
(
    UserTask_IDEntitat
)
```

Executing the following query, execution plan shows us that index on `UserTask_IDEntitat` is used to do the query:

```
SELECT UserTask_ID
  FROM UserTask   
 WHERE UserTask_IdEntitat = @IdEntitat 
 ORDER BY UserTask_LastSendSystemDateTime desc
```

But If we add another column in the `Select` list, then the index is not used

```
SELECT UserTask_ID, UserTask_SequenceNumber, UserTask_IDEntitat, ....., UserTask_Subject
  FROM UserTask   
 WHERE UserTask_IdEntitat = @IdEntitat 
 ORDER BY UserTask_LastSendSystemDateTime desc
```

Why adding a column different from the primary key makes that the SQL Server execution plan doesn't use the index on the `UserTask_IDEntitat` column?

Following this link http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/144592-sqlsever-not-using-index it seems that the number of times that the filtered value is repeated on the column, It can make that the index is not used, but I have tried doing the query with an @IdEntitat value that is repeated 60.000 times and other that is repeated only 175 times and the results are the same, the index on `IDEntitat` column is ignored.

This is taking me crazy!!!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're on a suitable version, and this is a common query, you might want to look into `INCLUDE`ing `_SequenceNumber` in the index.

Comment: ... and `LastSendSystemDateTime` also, I think. (To help do `order by`).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

OK - as long as you select only the column that's in the index, or something from the clustering key (usually, this is the primary key), then the index will be used, since SQL Server can find all the information it needs (the `UserTask_IDEntitat` column, and the clustered index column(s) ) in the leaf level of the index navigation structure. So it can return the data needed for that `SELECT` query directly from the index's leaf level pages.

**However:** if you need to select a second column, that is **neither** in the index definition, **nor** part of the clustering key, then SQL Server would have to do a so-called **bookmark lookup** into the actual data pages.

So ***for every single row it finds*** in your nonclustered index, it would have to take the clustering index value, search the clustered index to find the actual data page at the leaf level of that clustered index, and then pick out that one column that you want.

**Bookmark lookups** are great for small numbers of hits - they are totally devastating for performance if you're selecting thousands of rows. In that case, the SQL Server query optimizer correctly uses a **clustered index scan** instead - since in the clustered index, on the leaf level, it has **all the rows** available right away.

So: if you have an index on `UserTask_IDEntitat` and you sometimes need a second column `UserTask_SequenceNumber` too - then you could **include** that column in that nonclustered index of yours:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_UserTask_IDEntitat 
ON dbo.UserTask(UserTask_IDEntitat)
INCLUDE(UserTask_SequenceNumber)
```

With this, that additional column is present in the **leaf level** of that non-clustered index only (it cannot be used in a `WHERE` clause - it's not part of the navigation structure of the index!) - and your second `SELECT` can again be satisfied from the leaf-level nodes of the nonclustered index -> no expensive bookmark lookups are needed -> your index will be used again.

**Long story short:** unless your nonclustered index is ***highly selective*** (e.g. returns 1% of your rows or less), and unless your nonclustered index is a **covering index** (an index that contains all the columns needed to satisfy a particular query), then changes are pretty high that SQL Server will **NOT** use your nonclustered index.

**For more information**:

- [SQL Server Indexing Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics)
- [SQL Server – Learning SQL Server Performance: Indexing Basics – Video](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/03/08/sql-server-learning-sql-server-performance-indexing-basics-video/)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and your useful links, what I really need in production queries is not only return the UserTask_SequenceNumber, I need to return all columns, (The second query it was a bad example), in this case there isn't any easey optimitzation to do, no? SqlServer is doing the most effective way is possible.

Comment: @MarcCals: if you need **all** columns - then most of the time, indexes won't really help since doing a clustered index scan is usually more efficient than doing thousands of expensive bookmark lookups

Answer (score 2):

You can use the query hints in the query to make use of Index. Following is a link for further details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I faced with situation when the same query makes different plan on different databases. On the one DB it use non-clustered index and on the other - table scan.

Also this index doesn't have all field in INCLUDE, and the best solution here would be to add all necessary selected fields to index INCLUDE. In my case drop free cache helps though.

[DBCC freeproccache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-freeproccache-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Sometimes query plan builder ignores index if it has fragmentation more 50%, because it spend more time to find row in index than to scan the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it be the case where covering indexes are not used when there isn't a sufficient amount of data in the tables to sufficiently populate Statistics that the SQL Query Optimizer uses for Cardinality Estimation which ultimately impacts which indexes (if any) are chosen for the execution plan.

For instance, I ran the same sql query with the same input data across 3 distinct databases.  Running the stored procedure against each of the 3 databases yields the same output. All 3 databases have the same database options, settings, COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL, and schema.  There were two only differences between the databases:

1. the *amount* of data. The first 2 where the expected indexes were used had about 1000x more data than the 3rd where the indexes were not used.
2. The SQL-created statistics (prefixed with `_WA_Sys`). There were more auto-generated statistics in the databases where there was much more data. The other  had a few of the auto-generated statistics, but not all.

As a result, the Histograms for the covered indexes were much different causing the Query Optimizer to choose different execution plans.