# Sql Server 2012 not Using Index

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sqlperformance, non-clustered-index

I have a table with several columns. I am searching for username based on first or last name. When I run the query and check the execution plan, I notice that the index is not being used. What do I  need to do for SQL Server to use these indexes?

Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @fName nvarchar(50) = 'user'
       ,@lName nvarchar(50) = 'one';

SELECT userName
FROM Micro.MicroUser m
WHERE (m.firstName IN (@fName) OR @fName IS NULL)
OR (m.lastName in (@lName) or @lName IS NULL);
```

**This is the INDEXES that I created.**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MICROUSER_LNAME ON [Micro].[MicroUser]
(
  firstName asc
) INCLUDE(userName);
go
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MICROUSER_FNAME ON [Micro].[MicroUser]
(
  lastName asc
) INCLUDE(userName); 
go
```

[image]

**Update**

I was able to get it to use the index, but it's still doing an index scan instead of seek. In addition, If I removed the "or parameterName is null," it's doing a seek.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_test_lname_fname] ON [Micro].[MicroUser]
(
    [lastName] ASC,
    [firstName] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [userName])
```

Because of time constraint, I am going to use if statements to check for null values and run the different queries based on whether the firstname or lastname is null.

**Updated 1/25/2020**

I am still getting index scan; however, the workaround is producing index seek instead of scan.

```
DECLARE @fName nvarchar(50) = NULL
       ,@lName nvarchar(50) = 'one';

If  @lName IS NOT NULL AND @fName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT userName
    FROM Micro.MicroUser m
    WHERE (m.lastName IN (@lName))
    AND (M.firstName IN (@fName)) -- select * from Micro.MicroUser
END
ELSE IF @lName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
SELECT userName
    FROM Micro.MicroUser m
    WHERE (m.lastName IN (@lName))
END
ELSE IF @fName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
 SELECT userName
FROM Micro.MicroUser m
WHERE (M.firstName IN (@fName))
END
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858949/why-isnt-sql-server-using-my-index and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23509/why-is-this-query-not-using-my-nonclustered-index-and-how-can-i-make-it

Comment: Does it use the indexes if you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`? Those OR conditions will prevent it without that.

Comment: I ran DBCC FREEPROCCACHE to see if it'll use the index, but it did not.